# Is it possible to install custom NodeJS packages from a local server?

Tags: node.js, server

Is there a way to develop custom packages (such as 'awesome_css_framework'), store them on a local server, and then utilize the 'npm i' command to install and use them on my personal machine? While I am aware of Verdaccio's functionality, I'd like to have more control over the process. Are there any official guides available that can walk me through the setup for achieving this?

Answer (score 0):

You can publish your own packages (as unscoped public, scoped public and private). If you want your package to be available to specified users or only to yourself, you can publish as a private package.

See the guides from NPM's webpage: https://docs.npmjs.com/packages-and-modules/contributing-packages-to-the-registry

**Note:** You will need to create an account on NPM and github, if you don't have one.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible.

1. Choose a [scope](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v9/using-npm/scope) to identify packages such as "awesome_css_framework" (ex: @myregistry)
2. Configure [npmrc](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v9/configuring-npm/npmrc#auth-related-configuration) to connect to your private registry
3. [Associate your scope with your private registry](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v9/using-npm/scope#associating-a-scope-with-a-registry)